# How to install/upgrade a uninstalled release(--keep-history)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

After I uninstalled a release(with --keep-history), there will remain a release history with "uninstalled status".

Then if I want to install this release again, `install` and `upgrade --install` are both failed.

`install` failed because of "cannot re-use a name that is still in use"
but `upgrade --install` failed because of "xxx has no deployed releases"

Is the only way that I have to remove the history or uninstall without history?

I tried to use `install` and `upgrade --install` command, both failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described  in this  [doc](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/helm-has-no-deployed-releases) by phoenixnap.

**There are several ways to fix  the “helm has no deployed releases” error, one ways is by running the following command**:

```
kubectl -n kube-system patch configmap [release name].[release version] --type=merge -p '{"metadata":{"labels":{"STATUS":"DEPLOYED"}}}'
```

[release name]  is the name of the release you want to update.

[release version]  is the current version of your release.

Since Helm 3 stores the deployment history as [Kubernetes secrets](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/kubernetes-secrets). Check the deployment secrets:

```
kubectl get secrets
```

Find the secret referring to the failed deployment, then use the following command to change the deployment status:

```
kubectl patch secret [name-of-secret-related-to-deployment] --type=merge -p '{"metadata":{"labels":{"status":"deployed"}}}'
```

You can also refer this [blog](https://jacky-jiang.medium.com/how-to-fix-helm-upgrade-error-has-no-deployed-releases-mystery-3dd67b2eb126) by Jacky Jiang for more information about how to upgrade helm

Comment: It seems like the only way now, I'll do it this way, Thank you a lot !

Comment: I'm writing a software to deploy app with helm, using client-go. I found my secret name is like "sh.helm.release.v1.[appName].[revision]", is the secret of helm release always named like this ?

Answer (score 1):

I understand your need; I came across this problem some time ago.

What you described is exactly how Helm works, but you can try this workaround: after deleting the Chart (keeping the "uninstall" history), redirect the history to a file and save it to a Git repository. Finally, before installing again, delete the Chart permanently.

Example:

```
helm -n NAMESPACE uninstall APP --keep-history
```

```
helm -n NAMESPACE history APP -oyaml > APP-uninstall-log.yaml
```

(Push the file to the Git repository)

```
helm -n NAMESPACE uninstall APP
```

You won’t have any more problems.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I understand why you save the history to a yaml file, but I don't know how to use the history again, like how to add the history to the upgraded app(in fact, it is a new app now to helm)